# Mysql Inner join between 4 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have to do a mass update between tables (200.000 records) with INNER JOIN:

Table1 (data source):

```
CODE | AVAILABILITY | PRICE
```

Table2 (the only table with "CODE"):

```
ID | CODE
```

Table3 (destination table 1):

```
ID | PRICE
```

Table4 (destination table 2):

```
ID | AVAILABILITY
```

I have to:

```
1) SELECT ID from Table2 WHERE table1.code=table2.code LIMIT 1
2) UPDATE PRICE in Table3 WHERE table3.ID=table2.ID LIMIT 1
3) UPDATE AVAILABILITY in Table4 WHERE table4.ID=table2.ID LIMIT 1
```

How to achieve this using Mysql only, in a single query?

Comment: Can't be done.  You need a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UPDATE 
    table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3, table4 t4 
SET 
    t3.price=t1.price, t4.availability=t1.availability
WHERE 
    t1.code=t2.code AND t2.id=t3.id AND t2.id=t4.id
```

Comment: That whas so simple, and I messed up with Inner Joins without any reason! Thank you...